# Removing $x$ from $a\cos2x=b\sin x$ and $c\sin2x=d\cos x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I want to build an equations without $x$ using the following two equations.
$$\begin{align}
a \cos 2x &= b \sin x \\
c \sin 2x &= d \cos x
\end{align}$$

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thank you for your advice

Comment: Hint: You can express the first equation using only $\sin x$. The second equation, too ... provided you ignore certain values of $x$ (which you should consider separately).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $cos x\neq 0$:
From second equation, canceling $cos x$, we have:
$$sin x=\frac {d}{2c},     \frac {d}{2c}\neq \pm 1......(1)$$
From the first equation,
$$2a sin^2 x+b sin x-a=0$$
Substituting $(1)$ here, we get your required equation.
Assuming $cos x=0$:
$$\Rightarrow cos 2x=2cos^2 x-1=-1, and sin x=\pm 1$$
Hence, $-a=\pm b$
Hence, equations can be $a+b=0$ or $a-b=0$ depending upon whether $x=\frac {(4k+1)\pi}{2} or \frac {(4k-1)\pi}{2}$, respectively.